# Can't use function defined in "src" of same script element?

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I'm trying to work on some js code to:

- Create a nav menu
- Create a header, nav, ul, and li element(s) w/in js
- Be automatically invoked

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js1.js">
    cHeader();
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the js:

```
function cHeader(){
    var header = document.createElement("header");
    var body = document.getElementById("body");
    body.appendChild(header);
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    header.appendChild(ul);
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    ul.appendChild(li);
    var liNode = document.createTextNode("Home");
    li.appendChild(liNode);
}
```

When I try to call the function by either `<body onLoad="cHeader()">` or with `<script>cHeader()</script>` in the html, my console in Chrome returns with:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cHeader is not defined index.html:19
(anonymous function)
```

Although, even when I try inline script tags, the code won't do anything.

Comment: you must define the function before you call it...

Answer (score 8):

```
<script src="js1.js">
    cHeader();
</script>
```

should be:

```
<script src="js1.js"></script>
<script>cHeader();</script>
```

`<script>` tag with `src` attribute should not contain any thing inside.

Instead, after, loading the script, you need to call it in another `<script></script>`

Comment: With type="text/javascript" it would be even better

Answer (score 0):

try putting `window.onload=function(){cHeader();};` at the bottom of your javascript file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I think this is an answer; it should fix the issue. I can edit it to explain better, but this is a solution.